# Adding localization bundles in JasperServer Community edition

Tags: localization, internationalization, jasperserver

How does one add a localization bundle in JasperServer Community edition? Assuming I have an report called MyReport.jrxml and a bundle containing localization called MyReport.properties bundle, which work when run locally. However once I submit the .jrxml on the JasperServer CE and add a resource bundle to that report it doesn't seem able to find it.

Is there a way to do it, preferably without changing the Tomcat container that runs the JasperServer.

Comment: Your idea is right. JRS Community and Pro both ship with samples showing report localization in action. You might need screenshots or other details to somehow show what you're trying.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen the same problem.

In my case the problem was the name of the file. Note that if the resource bundle name is bundle.properties you have to set the property "Resource Bundle" in the report as "bundle". Then you will have probably other files as bundle_en.properties, bundle_ar.properties, etc.

have luck